# Sqlite fts4 case sensitive

Tags: sqlite, case-sensitive, fts4

Very new to Sqlite3 and I finally have an FTS4 search working, but am stumped how to code for Case-Sensitive. I have a Database with `tblMain` that has two BLOB_TEXT columns, `advOne` and `advTwo`

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tFind USING FTS4(aOne, aTwo);
// populate tFind here
SELECT FROM tFind WHERE aOne MATCH 'Fine';
```

This works fast and returns records with 
`feeling fine` and 
`a Fine was levied`

I need to find the records with only the case sensitive `Fine` in them.

How do I word the line?

I am using Lazarus and Ubuntu if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The default [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer) ignores case.

You'd have to install your own [custom tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#custom_application_defined_tokenizers).